# Linking the Backend (Node.Js)Express and the Frontend (React)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, android-studio

I want to merge two projects: one for the React frontend and the other for the NodeJs Express backend. I am using Android Studio to preview my front-end application on a phone emulator. I am not sure if you have any ideas on how I can get everything to work together.

I started by copying the front-end project and putting it at the root of the back-end project. Then, I set up a variable in the package.json file to be able to start the front-end from the back-end ("client": "cd my_frontend_project && npm start"). As for the next steps, I'm lost and I really don't know what to do.
Should I create a single file to start this connection, or several, knowing that my project comprises several pages/functionalities, and how do I set up this connection?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. first of all you need to start the backend and in case it is not implemented in backend the you should implement Cors,(which is a middleware)
2. you need to test the api using postman
3. end

Comment: Hi andi, thanks for your answer . I must admit that I have never worked with this methodology, im learning right now, so I have a folder in my backend named middleware which contains several files, its files are indexed by verify, I think it's for verification, but if you can give me more details / info on their uses and what I have to do with them I would be grateful

Answer (score 0):

to understand all of your code how the flow works inside some the functions try to write consoles  for example: console.log("auth-middleware") ,
console.log("error handler")

first of all start both of them Frontend and Backend
second check the port number that they are running
so in backend (Nodejs)
in index.js (the file that start the server)
try to set up the cors like this:

```
app.use(cors({
origin: ['http://localhost:8080',]
    methods: ['GET','POST','DELETE','UPDATE','PUT','PATCH']
}));
```